# Updating EF model in new DbContext instance

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, singleton, entity-framework-6

What is the best way to update an entity framework model in the database with two instances of a DbContext. For example i have a simple `User` model which is loaded in one `DbContext` but saved in another:

```
User model = null;

using(SampleDbContext dbContext = new SampleDbContext())
{
    model = dbContext.User.Find(0);
}

model.UserName = "Test-User";

using(SampleDbContext dbContext = new SampleDbContext())
{
    // Here is the place i want to save the changes of the model
    // without loading it again from the database and set each property

    // ...
    dbCotnext.SaveChanges();
}
```

In my case i want to write some `UserManager`, which has Create, Update and Delete methods. I think creating one DbContext instance for the howle manager
is no solution, because i only want to save the changes of a specific model.

I also **don't** want to load the models for updating again from the database and settings each value from the source instance, like:

```
// Update user
using(SampleDbContext dbContext = new SampleDbContext())
{
    // I don't want this:
    var model = dbContect.User.Find(0);
    model.UserName = sourceModel.UserName;
    // ...
   dbCotnext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Maybe my problem with manager classes is very simple, but i could not find any good solution.

P.S.: My manager classes are often singleton classes.

Thank you.

Comment: I really think you need to reword the question a little bit. It is very unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Would you like to explan which part is unclear? Or should i add some more code samples?

Comment: I don't know really. Do you just want to update records without first loading them from the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could in your second DbContext do something like this:

```
using (SampleDbContext dbContext = new SampleDbContext())
{
    dbContext.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

This would save the changes you have made to the entity to the database. However I can't remember if `dbContext.Entry` queries the DB for the entity.

Comment: dbContext.Entry does query the database if the entity is not already on the context. If you knew the entity existed you could just use `Attach` and set it to modified afterwards like you've shown.

Comment: @user2697817 thanks for that info. Yes I agree that `Attach` could also be used.

Comment: This works for me: `dbContext.Role.Attach(role);
                dbContext.Entry(role).State = EntityState.Modified;
                dbContext.SaveChanges();` (RoleManager). Thank you!